# Android achartengine FillOutsideLine with gradient color

Tags: android, achartengine

Can we use a gradient style for `FillOutsideLine` of `achartlibrary` to color the below side of the line ?

so far I managed to use simple `Color.argb()`, but I can't use any `xml` to make it gradient or it will crash

can we fix this issue ?

code:

```
FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);
fill.setColor(Color.argb(55, 62, 117, 163));
renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's bit tricky, but you can set FillOutsideLine ABOVE with your background color, make chart background transparent, and add gradient background to GraphicalView.

**Upd**

I'm using Xamarin for now, that's why  C#. Anyway, hope it helps :)

```
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            ...
            //Set up fill
            XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine fill = new XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine(XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.FillOutsideLineBehaviorType.Above);
            fill.Color = Color.White.ToAndroid();
            renderer.AddFillOutsideLine(fill);

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            mRenderer.AddSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            //Set chart background
            mRenderer.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.ToAndroid();
            ...

            chartView = ChartFactory.GetLineChartView(Forms.Context, dataset, mRenderer);
            //Set gradient background
            chartView.SetBackgroundResource(Droid.Resource.Drawable.chart_gradient);
```

Comment: Maybe you can support your answer with a code snippet?

Comment: Ok, but i'm using Xamarin for now, so it will be C#, sorry for that

Comment: Doesn't matter! The OP hasn't tagged the question to a specific language!

Comment: I have added to our copy of AchartEngine the ability to set the boundary of addFillOutsideLine() to something other than the horizon line. HMU if anyone wants to help productize my hack.